# Rotate-Transform the Two-Dimensional Matrix in js

Tags: javascript

I have to create a function to rotate a two-dimensional matrix of `N * N` integer elements num times, where if num is positive, the rotation is clockwise, and if not, counterclockwise.

Examples

```
rotateTransform([
   [2, 4],
   [0, 0]
], 1) /*➞ [
   [0, 2],
   [0, 4]
]*/
```

```
rotateTransform([
   [2, 4],
   [0, 0]
], -1) /*➞ [
   [4, 0],
   [2, 0]
]*/
```

**NOTE**: I couldn't even try...

Comment: I saw this somewhere

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: "NOTE: I couldn't even try..." -- why not?

Comment: I think this problem needs geometry... any way you can check it on [edabit](https://edabit.com/challenge/4nmXZTtvBoNbsEe22)

Answer (score 1):

For every possible num you enter there are only 3 *other* orientations and you can get there with at most 2 transforms:

```js
function rotateTransform(arr, num) {
  // turn 90deg clockwise
  if (num & 1) arr = arr.reverse().map((_, i) => arr.map(row => row[i]));
  // turn 180deg
  if (num & 2) arr.reverse().forEach(row => row.reverse());

  return arr;
}

for (let num = -10; num < 10; ++num) {
  console.log("num", num);
  console.log(rotateTransform([
    [2, 4],
    [0, 0]
  ], num).join("\n"))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```